# Area of regions in a Circle

Tags: geometry

Let $R$ be the circle centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $10.$ The lines $x = 6$ and $y = 5$ divide $R$ into four regions $R1, R2, R3,$ and $R4.$ Let $[Ri]$ denote the area of region $Ri.$ If $[R1] > [R2] > [R3] > [R4],$ then find $[R1]-[R2]-[R3]+[R4].$

I know which parts of the circle is $R1, R2, R3,$ and $R4.$ But I'm not sure how to find the areas of them.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  You'll get a much better response if your questions are easy to read.

Comment: How do I edit my question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3665302/edit

Comment: Are you allowed to use calculus for this?

Comment: Yes, I am allowed to use calculus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: rectangle in circle]

Flip $R_4$ (the orange region in upper right corner) with respect to $x$-axis and remove it from region $R_3$. You get the green region on the right which has area $[R_3]-[R_4]$.

Flip $R_2$ (the red region on top) with respect to $x$-axis and remove it from region $R_1$. Flip the green region on the right with respect to $y$-axis and remove it from what's remain on $R_1$. You get a blue rectangle with area $$\big([R_1] - [R_2]\big) - \big([R_3] - [R_4]\big) = [R_1] - [R_2] - [R_3] + [R_4]$$

The dimension of the rectangle is $12 \times 10$, so the answer is $120$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $R21 = R4 = R13$ and $R23 = R14$ and $R3 = R12 + R13,$ $$R1-R2-R3+R4 = R11.$$ $R11$ is a rectangle with side lengths $10$ and $12.$ So the area is $10*12 = 120.$

Comment: Some sketch will be helpfull

Comment: I don't know what you are referring to with $R21$ and such, but your solution is correct. You do not need to find the areas of the individual parts.